# Mover una imagen a otra localización en c#

Tags: c#

No sé cómo se puede hacer para que una imagen en una picturebox se mueva a otra localizacion mediante coordenadas dadas, de forma que si sucede un evento se pueda mover a una localización específica.

Comment: ¿Si sucede qué evento? ¿A que te referís con "una localización específica", simplemente a otra posición o se tiene que tomar referencia a otro control? ¿Y qué intentaste hasta ahora?

Comment: el evento es un click, una localizacion especifica me refiero a q se mueva la imagen a las coordenadas 200,200 por ejemplo, lo que quiero hacer es que la imagen se mueva en el mapa a una posicion

Comment: Lo que tengo que hacer es un juego como este:

Comment: http://juegosdelogica.net/juegosdeestrategia/gatosyraton_3.php  y la verdad no se muy bien como hacerle

Answer (score 1):

Una forma sencilla es manejando el evento `MouseClick`. El parámetro `MouseEventArgs` recibe las coordenadas del clic y gracias a ellas puedes mover cualquier control modificando su propiedad `Location`. Aquí tienes un ejemplo:

```
private void MainForm_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // Desplazas la imagen a las coordenadas del clic
    pictureBox1.Location = e.Location;
}
```